# Only want my website to get and post from my website and webserver

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have google and tried many solutions but none seemed working. So thats why I am asking it here finally.
I am new to aws and s3. I have checked `Block all public access` on my s3 bucket. So I am not able to view images from the url. Now I wanted to just add a policy which allows to get images only from my website. For that I went to their documentation and applied this bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy example",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::development-stockarea/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://developstockarea.herokuapp.com/*",
                        "http://developstockarea.herokuapp.com/*",
                        "https://stockarea-application-test.herokuapp.com",
                        "http://stockarea-application-test.herokuapp.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I tried to save it was showing me this thing:

```
Granting public access in this policy will be blocked because Block public access settings are turned on for this bucket. To determine which settings are turned on, check your Block public access settings.
```

So it seems my policy was not actually getting attached to the bucket. I also tried with CORS policy to give access to my website like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://developstockarea.herokuapp.com/*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

But this also seemed to have no effect. Can anybody give me detailed help or instruction where I am going wrong or something.

UPDATE:
Ok so after reading their docs I tried few things but it still not working correctly.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1488494182833",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1488493308547",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::892246803113:user/abhiraj-tulsyan"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:Put*",
                "s3:Delete*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::app-stockarea/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://app.stockarea.io/*",
                        "http://app.stockarea.io/*",
                        "https://admin-stockarea.herokuapp.com/*",
                        "http://admin-stockarea.herokuapp.com/*",
                        "https://stockarea.io/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my policy now. And I have unchecked the block all public access settings.
But still I am able to copy paste the url of the image and its getting shows without any  4xx error.

Answer (score 0):

"Amazon S3 block public access settings override these policies and permissions so that you can limit public access to these resources." from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html
This setting overrides all policies. The error you get says the same.
**So let's uncheck this option and everything should work :-)**

JSON for policy you shared looks enough to get what you want. It basically allows access only for specified Referers.
For more details see "Restricting Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer" section in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

Comment: I updated my answer for better insights. Any suggestions would be great

Comment: The same doc contains “Make sure the browsers you use include the HTTP referer header in the request.” If after this it doesn’t work still, then let’s simplify your policy to localize the problem. Example policy mentioned in that link is quite simple, it’s easy to understand what is wrong there. For first trying you don’t need a specific principal and strict actions.

Comment: I have referer header in my request. I checked that through dev console. The request header is making working perfect. But still not getting the blocking from other request